# How to choose my browser app as my default browser?

Tags: android, browser, webview

So I made a nice app for web browsing and it works pretty well.
When I launch my app, links are opened in my app and everything is going smoothly.
However, when I click on a link from outside the app (in a text message for example), Android is asking me which browser to choose to open my link, and mine isn't listed.
I'm trying to make my app able to open outside links and handle them.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT : SOLVED**

I found a way to make it work.
Here is a snippet of my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here is how I retrieve and use the intent that started my app with a link :

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    Uri startIntentData = getIntent().getData();
    if(startIntentData!=null) {
        String intentUrl = startIntentData.toString();
        if(intentUrl.contains("http://")||intentUrl.contains("https://")) {  // checking if the intent's data was meant to be a url
            addTab(intentUrl); // a method that handle opening urls by calling webView.loadUrl(String url)
        }
    }
```

I don't know if it's the most secure or the most efficient way, but at least it works!

Comment: This question and answer solved my problem. I want my app, which is a web browser, to be listed in the default web browser options in settings page, and also be listed in the web browser options when users scan a QR code to open an URL link. It is difficult to find similar questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to make my app my default browser

You don't. The *user* can elect to make your app be the default browser. Just set up an `<activity>` with the appropriate `<intent-filter>`, to watch for `ACTION_VIEW` `Intents` for whatever schemes and MIME types that you support. Android, and the user, will take it from there.

Comment: I don't want to force my app being the default browser, just to give the choice of opening links in my app. So this is a manifest problem? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Gueg: I do not know what your app can handle. I cannot tell you exactly what to include. `<intent-filter>` is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleFilters), plus books and courses on Android app development. See also existing open source Web browsers and what `<intent-filter>` elements they use, such as [Lightning](https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser/blob/dev/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) or [the AOSP browser](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser2/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: Thank you for your help,I finally found how to make it work. I mark your answer as accepted since your links really helped me to figure it out.